# Not getting getPastEvents or once function using contract instance

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, events, nodejs, npm

I have followed [Web3 documentation to subscribe an evnet](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents), I have created Instance of web3 using infura url as argument.

Created contract object using,

```
const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi, address)
```

Where abi and address containing Contract ABI and Contract Address respectively.

All documents and tutorials used web3.eth.**Contract** but it give TypeError: *web3.eth.Contract is not a Constructor*, so I have replaced it with 'c' web3.eth.**contract**.

The contract object returns, 
ContractFactory -> eth -> (List of functions) -> abi -> new 
In object structure.

I am not able to get an **Event** as object structure. Referred [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CX2QOE0FcEo) also.

I have web3 version: **0.20.7**, is there any problem with web3 version?

Comment: This web3 version is a few years old you should probably use a new one. Not sure if this is the error.

Comment: @Pave, Yes Exactly it's just a version issue. Now it works as given in web3 documentation and references.

Comment: Would be great if you could mark this question as solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This web3 version is a few years old you should probably use a new one.

Make sure to update!